# What are my options for cross program communication?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

A while ago i made a database framework in c++ and have been using it in various places, even made a wrapper for it for vb.net.

Now i have a new project that would require multiple programs accessing a single database and it would be wasteful to load up the database multiple times for every one of them not to mention the syncing horrors.

So I figured i would turn the framework into a standalone application and access to the data would be done in some xx magical way from those other programs. From what I've seen php and mysql do something like this..?

Problem is, I have no clue where to start. The only kind of cross program communication i've done is one program reading and writing directly into the other ones memory, seems kinda hacky though and I'm not sure if that sort of thing is going to fly with managed languages (I want to make it accessible in vb.net too).

Tips?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: oh yes, aiming for windows vista or newer

Comment: Did you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574.aspx ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most portable way to do [IPC (inter-process communication)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) is probably going to be [Sockets](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/586000/Networking-and-Socket-programming-tutorial-in-C).

Comment: Can you comment on the performance of this method? Something about networking just seems to whisper slow to me :o

Comment: @KarliRaudsepp - if you're going to run the applications on different machines then you're going to have to use the network!

Comment: Nothing is going to be as fast as shared memory, but on modern operating systems two processes communicating via sockets on the same machine is very fast since the OS is usually smart enough to recognize that they're both on the same machine and bypass the network stack.  This option also gives you more flexibility since it will allow you to run the processes on multiple machines.  It also can help reduce or eliminate many synchronization problems and race conditions.

Comment: hm, honestly I had not planned that as a feature but I wouldn't mind the option for future. I'm going to have to study that link before i can pose more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

What about [D-Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-bus)? There ist a port for Windows.